# Проблема в использовании ArrayList: Необработанное исключение типа "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" в mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, arraylist, множества, обработка-ошибок

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

namespace KAJlbKYJl9lTOP
{
    class Mnogg
    {
        public static ArrayList arrCopyA= new ArrayList();
        public static ArrayList arrCopyB = new ArrayList();
        public static int k = 0;
        public static string peresech = "";
        public static string ostatA = "", ostatB = "";
        public static string objedin = "";


        //Ввод множеств в консоль
        public static void inputEl()
        {


            string A = "";
            string B = "";

            Console.WriteLine("Введите элементы множества A через пробел: ");
            A = Console.ReadLine();



            Console.WriteLine("Введите элементы множества B через пробел: ");
            B = Console.ReadLine();

            //проверка на пустые строки
            if ((A == "")||(B == ""))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("WARNING! Введено пустое множество. Повторите ввод");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Mnogg.inputEl();
            }

            Mnogg.Konvert(A, B);

        }

        //Перевод строк в массивы
        public static void Konvert(string A, string B)
        {      ArrayList arrA = new ArrayList();
               ArrayList arrB = new ArrayList();

        //обработка строки А, занесение элементов в массив
        int position = 0;
            int start = 0;
            do
            {
                position = A.IndexOf(" ", start);
                if (position >= 0)
                {
                    arrA.Add(A.Substring(start, position - start + 1).Trim());
                    start = position + 1;
                }
                else
                    if ((start != 0) && (start < A.Length))
                {
                    arrA.Add(A.Substring(start, A.Length - start).Trim());
                    position = position - 1;
                }

            } while (position > -1);

            //обработка строки B, занесение элементов в массив
            position = 0;
            start = 0;
            do
            {
                position = B.IndexOf(" ", start);
                if (position >= 0)
                {
                    arrB.Add(B.Substring(start, position - start + 1).Trim());
                    start = position + 1;
                }
                else
                    if ((start != 0) && (start < B.Length))
                {
                    arrB.Add(B.Substring(start, B.Length - start).Trim());
                    position = position - 1;
                }

            } while (position > -1);

            arrCopyA = arrA;
            arrCopyB = arrB;

            /* foreach (Object obj in arrA)
                  Console.Write("   {0}", obj);
              Console.WriteLine();
              Console.WriteLine();
              foreach (Object obj in arrB)
                  Console.Write("   {0}", obj);
              Console.WriteLine(); */
        }

        //Метод определения пересечения множеств

        public static void Peresech()
        {

            k = 0;
            peresech = "";

            int na = arrCopyA.Count ;
            int nb = arrCopyB.Count;

            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            object a = arrCopyA[i];
            object b = arrCopyB[j];

            do
            {
                do {

                    **if (arrCopyA[i].Equals(arrCopyB[j])==true)**
                    {
                        peresech = peresech + arrCopyA[i] + " ";
                        k = k + 1;
                        arrCopyA.RemoveAt(i);
                        arrCopyB.RemoveAt(j);
                        j = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        j = j + 1;
                    }                                       
                } while (j<=4);
                i = i + 1;
                j = 0;
            } while (i<=4);

        }

        //метод определения объединения множеств
        public static void Objedinen()
        {
            objedin = null;
            int nA = arrCopyA.Count;
            int nB = arrCopyB.Count;
            for (int i=0; i< nA; i++)
            {
                objedin = objedin + arrCopyA[i] + " ";
            }
            objedin = objedin + peresech;
            for(int i=0; i< nB; i++)
            {
                objedin = objedin + arrCopyB[i] + " ";
            }
        }
        public static void Raznost()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Выберете разность множеств: a)А-B; b)B-A.");
            Console.WriteLine("Введите нужный номер и нажмите Enter: ");
            int w = Console.Read();
            if (w == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Разность множеств А - B : ");
                foreach (Object obj in arrCopyA)
                    Console.Write(" {0}", obj);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            if (w == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Разность множеств B - A : ");
                foreach (Object obj in arrCopyB)
                    Console.Write(" {0}", obj);
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.Read();

        }

        public static void SimmRazn()
        {
            objedin = null;
            int nA = arrCopyA.Count;
            int nB = arrCopyB.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < nA; i++)
            {
                objedin = objedin + arrCopyA[i] + " ";
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < nB; i++)
            {
                objedin = objedin + arrCopyB[i] + " ";
            }
        }

        //метод выбора нужной функции
        public static void Chose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Выберете нужную функцию:");
            Console.WriteLine("1.Пересечение ");
            Console.WriteLine("2.Объединение ");
            Console.WriteLine("3.Разность ");
            Console.WriteLine("4.Симметрическая разность ");
            Console.WriteLine("Введите нужный номер и нажмите Enter:");

            int c;
            c = Console.Read();
            switch (c)
            {
                case '1':
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Mnogg.Peresech();

                    if (k == 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Пересечения нет");
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.Write("Пересечение множеств А и B : ");
                        Console.WriteLine(peresech);
                    }

                    break;
                case '2':
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    if (k == 0)
                    {
                        Mnogg.Peresech();
                    }
                    Mnogg.Objedinen();
                    Console.Write("Объединение множеств А и B : ");
                    Console.WriteLine(objedin);
                    break;
                case '3':
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    if (k == 0)
                    {
                        Mnogg.Peresech();
                    }

                    Mnogg.Raznost();

                    break;
                case '4':
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    if (k == 0)
                    {
                        Mnogg.Peresech();
                    }
                    Mnogg.SimmRazn();

                    break;
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
            Mnogg.Chose();

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Операции над множествами с элементами в виде объектов");
            Mnogg.inputEl();
            Mnogg.Chose();
            // Ожидание нажатия клавиши Enter перед завершением работы
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Здесь фото ошибки]

Comment: а почему вы вообще `ArrayList` используете, а не просто `List<T>`?

Comment: Большая программа, да. (1) А почему вы не пользуетесь отладчиком? (2) А где у вас ошибка и при каких обстоятельствах она возникает, нам полагается догадаться, мыжпрограммисты?

Comment: @VladD, строка оказывается помечена `**` :-) `**if (arrCopyA[i].Equals(arrCopyB[j])==true)**[![Здесь фото ошибки][1]][1]`

Comment: @WeirdDark, просто проверьте значения `i`,`j` с количеством элементов в соответствующих листах

Comment: @Grundy: Ну, ТС мог бы посмотреть в отладчике, какой размер массива, и какой индекс он использует.

Comment: @VladD, ага, там у него жесткие числа в цикле забиты, я так смотрю ему не хватает  string.Join, и string.Split

Comment: @VladD, кстати, а `ArrayList` вообще еще используется где-то?

Comment: @Grundy: Не-а, он вроде бы не рекомендован. Тяжёлое наследие совместимости с первыми версиями языка, в которых не было генериков, а по политическим мотивам требовалась более-менее совместимость с Java.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в условиях остановки цикла

```
    } while (j<=4);
    i = i + 1;
    j = 0;
} while (i<=4);
```

Если в списках меньше 5 элементов, будете получать эту ошибку.

---

*Sidenote*: обратите внимание на функции [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx), и [string.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx), а также на класс [`HashSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx), они позволят сделать ваш код проще.